# True /False : If $P^*$ is a refinement of $P$, then $U(P^* ,f,a) \le U (P,f,a)$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I have  confusion in  Baby Rudin  theorem  $6.4$:

Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$, that is $a=x_0 \le x_1 \le \ldots \le x_n = b$,  $f$ is the function that we want to integrate, $\alpha$ is an increasing function on $[a,b]$, $M_i = \sup_{x_{i-1}\le x \le x_i} f(x)$ and $\Delta \alpha_i = \alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1})$.

Define $$U(P, f, \alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \Delta \alpha_i$$

**Theorem**: If $P^*$ is  a refinement   of  $P$, then $U(P^* ,f,\alpha) \le  U (P,f,\alpha)$

I think this statement is **N0T**  true

**My attempt** :  Let $f(x)= x$ .Take    $P=\{0,\frac{1}{4} ,1\} $ and  $P^*=\{0,\frac{1}{4} ,\frac{1}{2} ,1\} $

$w_1 = \sup \{f(x) | x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]\}=\frac{1}{2}$

$w_2 = \sup \{f(x) | x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]\}=1$

$M_i = \sup \{f(x) | x \in [0,1]\}=1$

Then  $U(P^*,f)- U(P,f)$  =  $w_1  + w_2 - M_i =\frac{1}{2} +1 -1  \ge 0 \implies  U(P^*,f)\ge U(P,f)$

Comment: Can you elaborate how you computed the difference $U(P^*,f)- U(P,f)$? I wonder why the point $x=1/4$ does not occur in the result.

Comment: Actually, that was my mistake  in thinking @MartinR

Comment: Btw, it is quite unlikely that a theorem (with proof!) in a textbook from Rudin is wrong.

Comment: Please include what $U$, $P$, $f$ and $a$ are. In the current form it takes a lot of guess work (or a copy of Rudin) to understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$w_1 = \sup \{f(x) | x \in [\frac14,\frac{1}{2}]\}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$w_2 = \sup \{f(x) | x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]\}=1$$

$$M_i = \sup \{f(x) | x \in [0,1]\}=1$$

Then  if $\alpha$ is an increasing function,\begin{align}&U(P^*,f)- U(P,f) \\ &=  w_1 (\alpha(1) - \alpha(0.5))  + w_2(\alpha(0.5) - \alpha(0.25)) - M_i(\alpha(1)-\alpha(0.25)) \\&=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha(1) - \alpha(0.5)) +1(\alpha(0.5) - \alpha(0.25)) -(\alpha(1)-\alpha(0.25))  \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha(1) - \alpha(0.5)) +1(\alpha(0.5) - \alpha(0.25)) -(\alpha(1)-\alpha(0.5) + \alpha(0.5) - \alpha(0.25))  \\
&=-\frac12(\alpha(1) - \alpha(0.5)) \le 0 \end{align}

I think your fallacy is to assume that we can have

$$\alpha(1)-\alpha(0.25) = \alpha(1)-\alpha(0.5)=\alpha(0.5)-\alpha(0.25)=1$$

Comment: Thanks for Edit .Actually ,i forgot to edit it@siang thye  Goh

Comment: you can still edit to include $w_1$ and $w_2$. :) good to have a reference to the book and at the same time, try to make it self-contained too.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t understand your computation. Why don’t you compute directly

$$\frac{11}{16}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}1=U(P^* ,f,a) \le  U (P,f,a)= \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4}1 =\frac{13}{16} $$

*By the way, I don’t have Rudin’s proof at hand of the theorem, but it is rather clear and simple.*